# Access elements in std::string where positon of string is greater than its size

Tags: c++, string, c++11, language-lawyer

In case of std::string, if we access an element where `(element position) == (size of string)` the standard says that it returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`.

```
const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
reference       operator[](size_type pos);
```

> Expects: pos <= size().
>
> Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(). Otherwise, returns a
>   reference to an object of type charT with value charT(), where
>   modifying the object to any value other than charT() leads to
>   undefined behavior.

http://eel.is/c++draft/strings#string.access-1

Unfortunately I couldn't reason about this, it would have been better if it has been Undefined Behavior.

Can somebody explain the rationale behind this?

Comment: isnt it just a question of where to put the UB? if you write `some_string[100] = 'a';` you have UB in both cases when the string is smaller than 100

Comment: @user463035818 Let's say "std::cout << some_string[100]", I think this is not an UB.

Comment: and why should it? If you decide to ignore the size of the string you deserve to pay a little extra ;)

Comment: @user463035818 you pay a little extra anyway

Comment: @Yola you mean because `operator[]` has to check if the index is `< size` in any case?

Comment: @user463035818 if it follows this, then yes. I am struggling to believe this ...

Comment: @user463035818 no that's not true. Subscript operator [] does not perform a check. `string::at()` does and for that reason it throws

Comment: Doesn't violating "Expects: `pos <= size()`" lead to UB straight away? The "Otherwise" refers only to the `pos == size` case, no?

Comment: @KostasRim Yes, at least Visual Stuido implementation, doesn't, but is it in accord with the standard?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Apparently it doesn't, atleast that's what standard says.

Comment: exactly I think the crux is "Expects: pos <= size()." if you dont follow the precondition you are in UB land anyhow, so it is just about accesing the "end" of the string

Comment: @AImx1 Where does the standard say that violating an "Expects" clause is anything other than UB?

Comment: For a C-style string of length X, using the index X will give you the null-terminator. `std::string` simply tries to emulate that. Going beyond will always lead to UB.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Check the returns of the Operator[]

Comment: @Yola visual studio does some vert tricky things so I can't be sure. First it's not very standard conformant second the implementation of STL is filled with hacks to support the visual studio debugger and all its unnecessary bloat (in the meantime I am checking the libstdc++) will update soon

Comment: VS (in debug builds) is within it's rights to checks bounds and throw in `[]`, because undefined behaviour allows *anything*.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have to consider the full specs.

First of all:

> Expects: pos <= size().

If you dont follow the precondition you have undefined behaviour anyhow. Now...

> Returns: *(begin() + pos) if pos < size(). Otherwise, returns a
>   reference to an object of type charT with value charT(), where
>   modifying the object to any value other than charT() leads to
>   undefined behavior.

The only (valid) case that "otherwise" refers to is when `pos == size()`. And that is probably to emulate c string behaviour that have a `some_string[size]` element that can be accessed. Note that `charT()` is typically just `'\0'`.

PS: One might think that to implement the specification, `operator[]` would have to check if `pos == size`. However, if the underlying character array has a `charT()` at the end of the string, then you get the described behaviour basically for free. Hence, what seems a little different from "usual" access into an array is actually just that.

Comment: Great explanation.  Also a great example how explaining unsupported cases (>size) leads to harder to follow specs.  'otherwise' should have read 'if pos==size'

Answer (score 22):

Statement 1 is the precondition for statement 2:

> 1. Expects: `pos <= size()`.
> 2. Returns: `*(begin() + pos) if pos < size()`.
>
>    Otherwise (***so here the only viable possibility is `pos == size()`***), returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()` (**i.e. `'\0'`**), where modifying the object to any value other than `charT()` leads to undefined behavior.

`str[str.size()]` basically points to the null-terminator character. You can read and write it, but you may only write a `'\0'` into it.

Answer (score 15):

The operator expects `pos` to be less than or equal to `size()`, so if it is not less, then it is expected to be equal.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to the previous answers please take a look at the `libcxx` (the llvm implementation) defines `std::string::operator[]` like:

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
inline
typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::const_reference
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::operator[](size_type __pos) const _NOEXCEPT
{
    _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__pos <= size(), "string index out of bounds");
     return *(data() + __pos);
}

template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
inline
typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::reference
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::operator[](size_type __pos) _NOEXCEPT
{
    _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__pos <= size(), "string index out of bounds");
    return *(__get_pointer() + __pos);
}
```

Take a look at the `.at()` that properly throws instead.

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::const_reference
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::at(size_type __n) const
{
    if (__n >= size())
        this->__throw_out_of_range();
    return (*this)[__n];
}
```

As you can, in the first case, there is a runtime assert(thanks t.niese for pointing out) which is triggered only in debug mode whereas the second will always throw, regardless of the build options of the library.

Comment: That's not a _static assert_ it is a runtime assert. A [static_assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) is something that is check at compile time, and a static assert is done for both release and debug builds.

Comment: `std::string name = "StackOverflow";`
`std::cout << name[100];` @t.niese If it a run time assert, why does the below code doesn't crash?

Comment: @AImx1 cause you didn't specify that you want the debug build when building the library?

Comment: @AImx1 because the standard says that `name[100]` is undefined behavior, and not that it must throw. `_LIBCPP_ASSERT` is a debugging assert that has to be explicitly enabled and is not automatically enable for regular debug builds, and it is run-time dependent [llvm: DebugMode](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/DesignDocs/DebugMode.html)

Comment: Also, putting aside the `_LIBCPP_ASSERT`, what this code snippet really shows is there is no test like `if (__pos >= size()) return _CharT()`, which is what would be needed for the behaviour the original question was expecting. Without a test like this, the only way `_CharT()` could be returned is if it is stored in the buffer pointed to by `data()`. Obviously this can't the case for all possible values of `__pos`, unless the buffer takes up all the memory on your computer!